# Offscreen UIView using Auto-layouts (programmatically)

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, uiviewanimation, nslayoutconstraint

This is very simple to do in the pre-autolayout domain but what is the programmatic way to insert a subview into a super-view such that subview is fully or partly off-screen:

[image]

A sample code that would add a subview so that its 5 pixels from top, bottom, left and right is:

```
NSDictionary* viewsDictionary = @{@"subview":subView};
[self.view addSubview:subView];
NSArray* horizontalMargins = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-5-[subview]-5-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
NSArray* verticalMargins = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[subview]-5-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];

[self.view addConstraints:horizontalMargins];
[self.view addConstraints:verticalMargins];
```

The answer to this question would help me implement slide in-out animation using auto-layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few hours of struggling and attempts I manage to produce the desired result with following code. I don't set any constraint for top but instead of that the height constraint is required so the subview knows how high to go.

```
NSDictionary* viewsDictionary = @{@"subview":subView};
NSArray* horizontalMargins = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[subview]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];

NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0 constant:0];

NSLayoutConstraint *bottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:-200];

heightConstraint.active = YES;
bottomConstraint.active = YES;

[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:horizontalMargins];
```

I am hoping changing constraints values within animation block will get me the slide in/out transition.

Answer (score 0):

I don't directly use NSLayoutConstraint but rather use PureLayout (https://github.com/smileyborg/PureLayout) to make the syntax slightly more friendly.

Using Purelayout I believe you could use the following code:

```
[subView autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeTop
                          withInset:-5.0f];

[subView autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeLeft
                          withInset:5.0f];

[subView autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeRight
                          withInset:-5.0f];
```

Comment: don't want an external library for something that simple, you can check my response